# GRUB after vmware conversion

Tags: grub

I'm stuck on that physical machine conversion (ubuntu 18.04 LTS) to VMware (Version 8). I get the conversion failed at 97% for the well known GrubInstall error

```
FAILED: An error occurred during the conversion: 'GrubInstaller::InstallGrub: /usr/lib/vmware-converter/installGrub.sh failed with return code: 127, and message: FATAL: kernel too old Error running vmware-updateGrub.sh through chroot into /mnt/p2v-src-root Command: chroot "/mnt/p2v-src-root" /vmware-updateGrub.sh "GRUB2" "(hd0)" "(hd0,1)" /vmware-device.map "grub2-install" '
```

Now I'm trying to follow some guides about Grub-reinstall but i'm stuck at partitions, the original machine has:

[image: Screenshot Physical]

The converted one (accessed via recovery iso)

[image: Screenshot VM]

I think that's the main problem about grub-install fails (on /dev/sda and /dev/sda1). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hdd splitting was done by VMWare converter, the old kernel message was not really realevant.

Solved with a workaround and not using the converter:

- Created an image of the entire Physical system with Clonezilla
- Restored the image on an empty VM
- Done some adjustment to the boot settings of the new-machine.

Thanks